# javascript draggable script tracking position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am following this guide: http://draggabilly.desandro.com/
which I think is hard to understand and I can't seem to figure out what to add to track the positions of the elements I drag around. If you look on the site, you can see the last example where they do it. My example so far is this:

```
   <div id="house_wall1">
            <img src="xxx" class="draggie" style="position:relative;">
            <img src="xxx" class="draggie" style="position:relative;">
            <img src="xxx" class="draggie" style="position:relative;">
            <!--Cypyrights and many thanks to http://desandro.mit-license.org for element movements -->
             <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
                <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
                <?php
                    echo $username;
                ?>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="draggabilly.pkgd.min.js"></script>


                            <script>
    ( function() {
      var container = document.querySelector('#house_wall1');
      var elems = container.querySelectorAll('.draggie');
      for ( var i=0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        var elem = elems[i];
        new Draggabilly( elem, {
      containment: true
      });
     }
   })();


function onDragMove( instance, event, pointer ) {
  console.log( 'dragMove on ' + event.type +
    pointer.pageX + ', ' + pointer.pageY +
    ' position at ' + instance.position.x + ', ' + instance.position.y );
}
// bind event listener
draggie.on( 'dragMove', onDragMove );
// un-bind event listener
draggie.off( 'dragMove', onDragMove );
// return true to trigger an event listener just once
draggie.once( 'dragMove', function() {
  console.log('Draggabilly did move, just once');


});
```

This script makes it possible to move the images around but it does not track their positions yet even though I have tried adding it at the bottom of the script as you can see. Does anybody have an idea what can be wrong or whats needed? I'm fairly new at Jquery, Javascript. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to this, Works fine for me. You just need to use offset() methods to get the position of dragged element when it is getting dragged and position() method to get the co ordinates of the position where it got dropped.

HTML:

```
//include these files.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src=" http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="container">
<img id="productid_1" src="Lionel Messi New Wallpaper 2012 07.jpg" class="item" alt="" title=""  height="100px" width="100px"/>
<img id="productid_2" src="bienvenidos_a_uniformes_deportivos_monterrey_4_216235520.jpg" class="item" alt="" title="" height="100px" width="100px" />
<img id="productid_3" src="lionel-messi-wallpapers-hd.jpg" class="item" alt="" title="" height="100px" width="100px"/>

        <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
        <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
        <?php
            echo $username;
        ?>
</div>

<div id="start">Waiting for dragging the image get started...</div>
<div id="stop">Waiting image getting dropped...</div>
<ul>
    <li id="posX"></li>
    <li id="posY"></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

JQUERY:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".item").draggable({

drag: function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    },

// Find original position of dragged image.
start: function(event, ui) {

    // Show start dragged position of image.
    var Startpos = $(this).position();
    $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
},

// Find position where image is dropped.
stop: function(event, ui) {

    // Show dropped position.
    var Stoppos = $(this).position();
    $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
}
});
});

</script>
```

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".item").draggable({
containment: '#limit_div',
drag:function(){......
//where #limit_div will be parent div of the #container div.
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the code but I would like to use the methods shown in the guide since I don't want to mix too many different scripts together. I can now track the image position but I can't output the result.. hmm

Comment: Actually, I tried most simplified code, yours was bit complicated. In my example, the output is getting displayed using .text() method.You can try this if u want.

Comment: @user33164770 oh yeah it works quite well, however, is it possible to do so the images can't move all over the page, but only in a specific div? thanks

Comment: The positioned elements has to start from the div top as well instead of the body so users with other resolution gets other positions. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah..it is possible. You need to use 'containment' property of draggable element. check my EDIT.